# How to add multiple inputType in TextField Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have one `TextField` using Jetpack Compose. In that field, I want only Number and Text input. I can apply to only one property at the same time. Like below,

```
TextField(
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text)
```

How can I add Text and Number input types?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text)
```

> How can I add Text and Number input types?

The type mentioned is to specify keyboard type as the parameter name implies `keyboardType`.
You can't show two keyboards at once.
So multiple keyboard types have no meaning.

---

From your question, I am guessing you want to show the soft keyboard which has both letters and numbers. (Comment below if that is not the case)

Use `KeyboardType.Password` for that.

[image: KeyboardType.Password]

**Extras**.

**KeyboardType.Text**.
[image: KeyboardType.Text]

**KeyboardType.Number**.
[image: KeyboardType.Number]

**KeyboardType.NumberPassword**.
[image: KeyboardType.NumberPassword]

Comment: I want TextField which accepts only capital letters with the number only. Don't want a special character tobe enter.

Comment: You have to create a custom keyboard for such a customized use case.

Comment: I have applied regex in `valueChange` property for `TextField` and its works.

Comment: Restricting input of certain characters and changing keyboard type are completely different things.

Comment: Yes, we don't have the option to apply two keyboard types as we have an option in XML. So, for time being I have added the above solution and its works.